# Disable Chrome Extension via Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to disable a Chrome Extension via Javascript?
The scenario is: a user accesses my web page, some javascript code runs and detects that a Chrome Extension called "MyTestChromeExtension" is installed, the javascript disable the chrome extension

Alternatively: Navigating the web it is common to see a popup when the Chrome Extension AdBlock is enabled, the popup prevents the user to navigate the web site until the extension is disabled (here I will prefer until the user uninstall the extension)

Thanks for your help

Comment: No. Extensions are a part of user preferences and browser UI so sites can't disable them. [Only an extension can disable another extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled) and even then there are restrictions.

Comment: If this *was* possible, the problem ad networks have with ad blocking extensions would be solved quite literally overnight.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few scripts you can use that may or may not work.

One method is to use the Fog Network's Ingot CDN through a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function () {var a = document.createElement('script');a.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/FogNetwork/Ingot/ingot.min.js';document.body.appendChild(a);}())
```

Copy this, save it as a bookmark, then go to any page (you cannot do it on a new tab) and open the bookmark. It will redirect you to an error screen. Click the "redirect" button and you will see it. Run the bookmark again, and you will see a list of your installed extensions. There is an enable/disable switch on each extension. If you disable it via. the switch, it should work.

Another bookmarklet:

```
javascript:void function(){"chrome.google.com"===location.hostname%26%26location.pathname.startsWith("/webstore")%3Fchrome.management.getAll(a=>{function b(a){chrome.webstorePrivate.getExtensionStatus(a.id,b=>{if("force_installed"===b){const b=prompt(`What do you want to do with ${a.name}%3F (enable/disable)`);var c=""===a.homepageUrl%3F`<b><a title="${a.description}">${a.name}</a></b>`:`<b><a href="${a.homepageUrl}" title="${a.description}">${a.name}</a></b>`,d="";"disable"===b.toLowerCase()%3F(chrome.management.setEnabled(a.id,!1),d+=`<p>Disabled ${c}</p>`):"enable"===b.toLowerCase()%3F(chrome.management.setEnabled(a.id,!0),d+=`<p>Enabled ${c}</p>`):alert("Invalid option, try again!"),document.body.innerHTML+=d}})}document.body.innerHTML="",document.write("\n<link rel=\"preconnect\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com\">\n<link rel=\"preconnect\" href=\"https://fonts.gstatic.com\" crossorigin>\n<link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2%3Ff...\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n<style>\n  body {\n      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;\n  }\n  a {\n      text-decoration: none;\n      color: blue\n  }\n  p {\n      margin: 0px\n  }\n</style>\n<h1 style=\"text-align: center\">Extension Panel</h1>\n"),a.forEach(a=>b(a))}):(alert("Run this script again but while on this page"),location.href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore_")}();
```

Use the same method given previously to run this as a bookmarklet. It will show an error screen. Run the bookmark again. It will ask you what you want to do. To get to the extension you want, click cancel until you see the name, then type disable in the text box.

How to know if this works:
If the extension is pinned, once you run the bookmarklet, it will disappear. If it isn't, check your extensions. If you do not see it, it worked. Otherwise, the script didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

javascript: void function () [{"chrome.google.com":location.hostname%26%26location.pathname.startsWith("/webstore")%3Fchrome.management.getAll(a=>{function b(a){chrome.webstorePrivate.getExtensionStatus(a.id,b=>{if("force_installed"===b){const b=prompt(`What do you want to do with ${a.name}%3F (enable/disable)`);var c=""===a.homepageUrl%3F`<b><a title="${a.description}">${a.name}</a></b>`:`<b><a href="${a.homepageUrl}" title="${a.description}">${a.name}</a></b>`,d="";"disable"===b.toLowerCase()%3F(chrome.management.setEnabled(a.id,!1),d+=`<p>Disabled ${c}</p>`):"enable"===b.toLowerCase()%3F(chrome.management.setEnabled(a.id,!0),d+=`<p>Enabled ${c}</p>`):alert("Invalid option, try again!"),document.body.innerHTML+=d}})}document.body.innerHTML="",document.write("\n<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">\n<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>\n<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2%3Ff..." rel="stylesheet">\n\n  body {\n      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;\n  }\n  a {\n      text-decoration: none;\n      color: blue\n  }\n  p {\n      margin: 0px\n  }\n\n<h1 style="text-align: center">Extension Panel\n"),a.forEach(a=>b(a))}):(alert("Run this script again but while on this page"),location.href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore_")}();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).